# Trouble installing Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

This is my first time working with this CMS.
I uploaded the [latest](https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/) release of umbraco to my host and instead of the "installation wizard" i  get the following error:
Internal server error - 500

There is a problem with the resource you are looking for and it cannot be displayed

Does this error indicate a error on the server-side or is this something that i can fix?

[URL to the website](http://bit.ly/1Gq2Fbc)

Thanks for all the help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hi c0ral 500 is a soft error which you will need to switch debug on in the web.config file to see the actual error. You might find your hosting partner doesn't support the required dependencies for umbraco to run like ASP.Net 4.5.

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Requirements/